# Dynamic listview or text view when data is picked from database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I'm new to android development and stuck somewhere. Can anybody please help me to understand eg :- if there is a list view of 3 fruits and we want to fetch dynamically 50 different fruits name in a list view or text view.

Could somebody please help me with the code for regarding the above

Comment: please remove irrelevant tag i.e PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will update dynamically with the collection of data(can be array, arraylist) you pass to adapter. fetch data and update your array,

call, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();